# BrowserSync proxy with Gulp, MAMP, Foundation and Craft CMS

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

A similar question has been asked a few times, but none of the answers are working for me. I'm trying to set up BrowserSync with a proxy of `localhost:8888` for. My gulpfile is from the Foundation Framework ZURB template.

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
import gulp          from 'gulp';
import browser       from 'browser-sync';

// Other Gulp functions

function server(done) {
  browser.init({
    proxy: 'localhost:8888'
  }, done);
}

function reload(done) {
  browser.reload();
  done();
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch(PATHS.assets, copy);
  gulp.watch('templates/**/*.html').on('all', gulp.series(browser.reload));
  // Other gulp tasks
}
```

Running Gulp shows that BrowserSync is proxying:

```
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8888
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.0.113:3000
 -----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
```

I've tried http://localhost:8888 and 127.0.0.1:8888, doesn't help. My file structure:

```
gulpfile.babel.js
/src (asset source)
/web (dist location)
/templates (Craft CMS templates, all .html files)
```

Everything else in Gulp is running smoothly, I just can't get the proxy to reload or inject styles.

Answer (score 0):

Now working with this update to the server function:

```
function server(done) {
  browser.init({
    port: '8890',
    proxy: 'localhost:8888',
    reloadOnRestart: true
  }, done);
}
```

Go to `localhost:8890` and viola!